# How to order reference in admin on rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

is there a way to order a reference inside a document in admin on rest?

Example: i have a product page with many categories (ReferenceArrayInput). is there a way to order the reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the `sort` prop: https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#referencearrayinput